# XMLHttpRequest to webservice not working in web worker

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

The code below runs perfectly if called from main javascript, but it does not run in the web worker.

```
  function getSpecData(detailLvl, startWeek, endWeek, mkt) {
        var params = { "detailLvl": detailLvl, "startWeek": startWeek, "endWeek": endWeek, "mkt": mkt };
        var xhr;
        var url = "WebServices/wsSProgress.asmx/GetSpecProgressTable";
        try {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    $('#specProgTbl').html(result.d);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Error occured in XMLHttpRequest: ' + xhr.statusText + '  ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status);
        }
    }
```

The only difference in the web worker code is that it uses postMessage to return the result:

```
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">

    self.onmessage = function (e) {
        var data = e.data;
        //self.postMessage(data.mkt + " " + data.detailLvl + " " + data.refreshMin + " " + data.isRotate +" "+data.weekNum);

        var startWeek=data.weekNum-3;
        var endWeek=data.weekNum;
        self.postMessage(getSpecData(1,startWeek,endWeek,data.mkt));

    }; 
    function getSpecData(detailLvl, startWeek, endWeek, mkt) {
        self.postMessage('DetailLvl '+detailLvl+' Start '+startWeek+' End '+endWeek+' Mkt '+mkt); 
        var params = { "detailLvl": detailLvl, "startWeek": startWeek, "endWeek": endWeek, "mkt": mkt };
        var xhr;
        var url = "WebServices/wsSpecProgress.asmx/GetSpecProgressTable";
        try {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    self.postMessage(result.d);
                }
            }; 
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        } catch (e) {
            self.postMessage('Error occured in XMLHttpRequest: ' + xhr.statusText + '  ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status);
        }
    }

</script>
```

The main javascript starting the worker:

```
  $(function initialize() {
        $('#options').hide();
        $("[id$='btnViewOpt']").val("View Options");
        var mkt = $("[id$='lstMkt'] :selected").text();
        var detailLvl = $("[id$='lstDetailLvl'] :selected").val();
        var refreshMin = $("[id$='lstRefresh'] :selected").val();
        var isRotate = $("[id$='chkRotate']").is(":checked");

        var BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        if (BlobBuilder) {
            var bb = new BlobBuilder();
            bb.append(document.querySelector('#worker').textContent);
            wUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb.getBlob());
            worker = new Worker(wUrl);
            alert("Web worker started");
            worker.addEventListener('message', dispMsg, false);
            worker.addEventListener('error', onError, false);
            worker.postMessage({ 'mkt': mkt, 'detailLvl': detailLvl, 'refreshMin': refreshMin, 'isRotate': isRotate, 'weekNum': getCurrentWeekNumber() }); // Start the worker.
        }
        else
            alert("Your browser does not support web workers");
 });

  function onError(e) {
        alert('ERROR in WebWorker: Line ' + e.lineno + ' in ' + e.filename + ': ' + e.message);
    }
    function dispMsg(e) {
        alert("Message from worker: " + e.data);
        $('#specProgTbl').html(e.data);

    }
```

The web worker starts and the params are correct but **result.d is undefined**. The catch has no statusText and just **readyState=0** and **status=0**. 
 What sorcery is this???

**UPDATE**
**xhr.responseText** if called from main Javascript is:

```
   {"d":"\u003ctable border=\u00271px\u0027 cellpadding=\u00275\u0027 cellspacing=\u00270\u0027\u003e\u003ctr height=\u002710\u0027 \u003e\u003cth height=\u002710\u0027 colspan=\u002712\u0027\u003ePAS\u003c/th\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr height=\u002710\u0027 \u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027200\u0027\u003eManufacturer\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027150\u0027\u003eMake\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eNoSpec W22\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eComplete% W22\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eNoSpec W23\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eComplete% W23\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eNoSpec W24\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eComplete% W24\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eNoSpec W25\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eComplete% W25\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eNoSpec W26\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027 width=\u0027100\u0027\u003eComplete% W26\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr height=\u002710\u0027 \u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027  class=\u0027default\u0027  height=\u002710\u0027 \u003eAAD\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027  class=\u0027default\u0027  height=\u002710\u0027 \u003eCHERY\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027 class=\u0027noSpecSame\u0027  height=\u002710px\u0027 \u003e0\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027  class=\u0027percSame\u0027  height=\u002710\u0027 \u003e\u003cdiv style=\u0027background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgba(8,68,250,1) 18%, rgba(240,241,250,1) 92%, rgba(240,241,250,0) 8%);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left , rgba(8,68,250,1) 18%, rgba(240,241,250,1) 92%, rgba(240,241,250,0) 8%);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left , rgba(8,68,250,1) 18%, rgba(240,241,250,1) 92%, rgba(240,241,250,0) 8%);background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgba(8,68,250,1) 18%, rgba(240,241,250,1) 92%, rgba(240,241,250,0) 8%);background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left , rgba(8,68,250,1) 18%, rgba(169,199,245,1) 92%, rgba(240,241,250,0) 8%);background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,right bottom,color-stop(0.18, rgba(8,68,250,1)),color-stop(0.92, rgba(240,241,250,1)),color-stop(1, rgba(240,241,250,0)));\u0027\u003e92\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027left\u0027 class=\u0027noSpecSame\u0027  height=\u002710\u0027 \u003e0\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align=\u0027center\u0027  class=\u0027percSame\u0027 height=\u002710\u0027 \u003e\u003cdiv style=\u0027background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgba(8,68,250,1) 18%, rgba(240,241,250,1..............."}
```

Comment: What if you send the whole of result to the parent?

Comment: @Jivings result is also undefined

Comment: @Jivings using FF13 and Chrome 19.

Comment: Well are you sure your webservice is returning data?

Comment: @Jivings The first section in my question shows the same function I tested in the main javascript. It works perfectly there and returns data.

Comment: @Jivings The contents of e is: DOMException: INVALID_STATE_ERR

Comment: If you'd posted that in your question then the answer would have been clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I was really stupid here. The reason why I was getting the

```
 DOMException: INVALID_STATE_ERR
```

was because according to [W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/) the **xhr.status** attribute throws an exception if **xhr.readyState** has an invalid value:

```
    Exceptions on retrieval
    DOMException  INVALID_STATE_ERR exception SHOULD be raised if this attribute is accessed when readyState has an inappropriate value.
```

I had an invalid **xhr.readyState** since I did not specify a full path to the webservice I am calling. The **full path to the webservice is needed** because the webworker runs in the separate **Blob file** created "on the fly". 
 Anyway, below is the webwoker code with working webservice call script:

```
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">

    self.onmessage = function (e) {
        var param = e.data;
        var url="http://localhost:54071/WebServices/wsSProgress.asmx/GetSpecProgressTable";
        var data=getSpecData(param.detailLvl,param.startWeek,param.endWeek,param.mkt,url)
        self.postMessage(data);
    }; 
    function getSpecData(detailLvl, startWeek, endWeek, mkt, url) {
        var params = { "detailLvl": detailLvl, "startWeek": startWeek, "endWeek": endWeek, "mkt": mkt };
        var xhr;
        try {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, false);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    self.postMessage(result.d);
                }
            }; 
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        } catch (e) {
            self.postMessage('Error occured in XMLHttpRequest: ' + xhr.statusText + '  ReadyState: ' + xhr.readyState + ' Status:' + xhr.status + ' E: ' +e+' Msg:'+e.message);
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error. I am trying to upload the heavy images in the web worker (~6MB). It works fine for 1 or 2 files, but it fails for more file ~6 files. Are there some memory constraints on Web Worker?

Comment: This fix also resolved the InvalidURL message I was gettting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From comments, your exception is:

```
DOMException: INVALID_STATE_ERR
```

This means that the contents of your message being posted back to the parent cannot be serialized.

In my experience, this is usually because of circular references or functions present in the object. Without knowing the response that the server is giving, this is as much as I can help you.

Comment: AFAIK when I use postMessage(result.d) to pass the data to the main javascript it gets parsed to JSON by the browser. The webservice returns an HTML table as a string. How would I have to return that so that it can be serialized?

Comment: @EwaldStieger You'll have to post the webservice response first.

Comment: Tried call a simple method within the web worker that returns {"d":"\"Hello World\""} and still get same error. Could it be a permissions issue because the webservice is called in a blob?

Comment: @EwaldStieger: Possibly, I didn't really understand that part of your code.